# How to return an array if the request not passed the middleware in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-middleware

I'm using Laravel for backend and AngularJS for handle the front-end. The problem is the angularjs call ajax to controller to get the data, otherwise the `auth` middleware, i want to add 1 more middleware called `apiKeyAuth` to check if end user send request with valid api key. But after i check the conditional inside `apiKeyAuth`, it give me an error in `\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php`. The return type of invalid api key is an array. Below is my code.

*APIKeyAuth Middleware:

```
class APIKeyAuth
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->get('api_key') != 'MyAPIKey'){
            return ['status' => 401, 'message' => 'Invalid API Key.', 'data' => null];
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should return a `JsonResponse` instead of an array:

```
class APIKeyAuth
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->get('api_key') != 'MyAPIKey'){
            return Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse::create(
                ['message' => 'Invalid API Key.'],
                Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED
            );
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware checks for a valid csrf token. It runs before your custom middlewares.

By default, your ajax requests don't include an csrf token.

If you make requests from your frontend, simply add a csrf token to your requests.
E.g. Axios:

```
window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}
```

If you want to access your api from outside your frontend, consider moving your api routes into the dedicated `routes/api.php` file or disabling csrf protection on these routes: [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris)

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    protected $except = [
        'stripe/*',
        'http://example.com/foo/bar',
        'http://example.com/foo/*',
    ];
}
```

Also, as @matei-mihai suggested, use JsonResponse to return your array

Comment: But i want to be an array to response to my ajax call then i will show the alert, not show new page...@@

Comment: Yes, a JsonResponse converts your array to a response. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/responses#json-responses